# Image sheaf is the sheafification of the image presheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

This is an exercise in Vakil's notes on foundations of algebraic geometry.

> Suppose $\Phi:\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{G}$ is a morphism of sheaves of abelian groups, show that the image sheaf Im $\Phi$ is the sheafification of the image presheaf.

My solution

> We use the key fact that in an abelian category, there is a natural isomorphism (preserving the arrow $\mathscr{F}\to \cdot $) between 
>   $$\text{Im }\Phi := \ker\text{coker}\,\Phi \cong \text{coker}\ker \Phi$$
>   Therefore we have 
>   $$ \text{Im }\Phi \cong \text{coker}\ker \Phi = (\text{coker}_{pre} \ker \Phi)^{sh} = (\text{coker}_{pre} \ker_{pre} \Phi)^{sh} \cong (\text{Im}_{pre}\Phi)^{sh} .$$

Is this solution correct? To be rigorous, I must define a map between Im$_{pre} \Phi\to $Im $\Phi$.

Comment: Well, have you proved that you can switch those two things in the category of Abelian sheaves?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that the natural map between them is an isomorphism. This holds in any abelian category, and in fact characterizes abelian categories (from additive categories).

Comment: Would this argument work?

Comment: $$
\text{Im}\Phi\cong\ker\text{coker}\Phi=\ker(\text{coker}_{pre}\Phi)^{sh} = (\ker_{pre}\text{coker}_{pre}\Phi)^{sh} \cong \text{Im}_{pre}\Phi^{sh}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another proof:

We know that the kernel and cokernel can be described in terms of compatible collections of germs. Using this characterization, the categorical image ($=\ker \operatorname{cok} \Phi$) should be the elements of $$\prod_{x \in X}\Phi_x(\mathscr{F}_x)$$
which are $\mathscr{G}$-compatible.

Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the image presheaf.

**Lemma:** Let $\mu \in \prod_{x \in X}\Phi_x(\mathscr{F}_x)$ be $\mathscr{G}$-compatible. Then $\mu$ is $\mathscr{P}$-compatible. (Note of course any $\mathscr{P}$-compatible collection is $\mathscr{G}$-compatible.)

**Proof:** Let $g$ be a section as in the definition of a compatible collection of germs, i.e. $g \in \mathscr{G}(U)$ be such that $g_y = \mu_y$ for all $y \in U$. Let $x \in U$. Since $\mu_x$ is in the image of $\Phi_x$, there is a neighborhood $V \subset U$ and $f \in \mathscr{F}(U)$ so that $\Phi_U(f) = g'$, and $g'_x = \mu_x$. Since $g'$ and $g$ have the same germ at $x$, after perhaps shrinking $V$, we have $g=g' \in \mathscr{G}(V)$. Taking such a representative for each $x$, we have shown the collection to be $\mathscr{P}$-compatible. $\blacksquare$

Hence the categorical image can be described as $\mathscr{P}$-compatible elements of $\prod_{x \in X}\Phi_x(\mathscr{F}_x)$. Now recall that the stalks of $\mathscr{P}$ are isomorphic to the images of the stalk maps $\Phi(\mathscr{F}_x)$. Therefore the categorical image is just $\mathscr{P}$-compatible elements of $\prod_{x \in X} \mathscr{P}_x$, which is just another way of saying the sheafification of $\mathscr{P}$.